# Classes: methods not intrinsically related to an object vs functions

Tags: javascript, class

I'm new to JavaScript, currently learning classes.

I made a simple class that creates a square with a random size and color:

```js
class Square {
  constructor(maxSize = 150, minSize = 50) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    this.minSize = minSize;
    this.size = this.setRandomSize();
    this.color = this.randomColor();
  }

  createShape() {
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.classList.add('square');
    document.body.appendChild(square);

    square.style.cssText = `
      width: ${this.size}px;
      height: ${this.size}px;
      background-color: ${this.color};
    `;
  }

  randomNumber(max, min = 0) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }

  setRandomSize() {
    return this.randomNumber(this.maxSize, this.minSize);
  }

  randomColor() {
    return `hsla(${this.randomNumber(360)}, 50%, 40%, .7)`;
  }
}

new Square().createShape();
```

As you can see in the code above, I've a 2 methods `randomNumber` and `setRandomColor` that don't use any instance or method properties.

I'm wondering what is the recommended approach or benefits (apart from portability) between having these functions inside or outside the class (as showed below). In other words, **is it recommended to keep inside the class methods that are intrinsically related to the object only (code block 2) or methods that allow the class to work as a "stand alone" (code block 1)?**

```js
class Square {
  constructor(maxSize = 150, minSize = 50) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    this.minSize = minSize;
    this.size = this.setRandomSize();
    this.color = randomColor();
  }

  createShape() {
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.classList.add('square');
    document.body.appendChild(square);

    square.style.cssText = `
      width: ${this.size}px;
      height: ${this.size}px;
      background-color: ${this.color};
    `;
  }

  setRandomSize() {
    return randomNumber(this.maxSize, this.minSize);
  }
}

function randomNumber(max, min = 0) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function randomColor() {
  return `hsla(${randomNumber(360)}, 50%, 40%, .7)`;
}

new Square().createShape();
```

Comment: Hi! Please review the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) *"This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers."* (with the implied *"...or removed if it can't be."*) Basically, this is a matter of opinion, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar confusion when I started to learn programming.
Since it is class, I would like to highlight [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) here.

**S**ingle Responsible : A class should do one thing.
Does your class's job is creating random number? You created the class because you wanted a Square, not a random size generator.

Also, if you put the functions outside of the class and use it there, your class will be coupled with those functions. What will you do if you need use rgb color instead of hsla? Another class? So less coupling will increase your class's quality.

So how I would write the class?

```
class Square {
    constructor(size, color){
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.square = document.createElement('div');
        this.square.classList.add('square');
        document.body.appendChild(this.square);
    
        this.square.style.cssText = `
          width: ${this.size}px;
          height: ${this.size}px;
          background-color: ${this.color};
        `;
    }
}


function randomNumber(max, min = 0) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
  
function randomColor() {
    return `hsla(${randomNumber(360)}, 50%, 40%, .7)`;
}

const size = randomNumber(100, 50)
const color = randomColor()
const mySquare = new Square(size, color)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me clear many ambiguities I had even if in the end, with the example I provided, I no longer need a class.

Comment: Well depends on how you will use the class. There are many cases that you can use this class like, following DOM objects you created, Object poolings and etc.  But I am glad it helped.